# PHP syntax issue

Tags: php, authentication

I'm reading a [Sentry tutorial](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/se-sentry/index.html) for implementing an authentication workflow in a webapp. I'm a PHP beginner. There's a thing I don't understand in this code:

```
<?php
// set up autoloader
require ('vendor\autoload.php');

// configure database
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=appdata;host=localhost';
$u = 'sentry';
$p = 'g39ejdl';
Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Native\Sentry::setupDatabaseResolver(
  new PDO($dsn, $u, $p));
[...]
```

What is the meaning of `Cartalyst\Sentry\Facades\Native\Sentry`? What's happening there? Is it a server file path? While debugging I found that this line doesn't execute.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because questions about PHP code are best asked at http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 1):

You have a case of PHP syntax for namespaces, this has nothing to do with path and filenames on disk.
See this introduction: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php
(even if it compares PHP namespaces to concept of disk directories and files, it is an analogy, not a 1-1 mapping)

It sure should execute.